# When you run through an array, does the key value pairs go into the hashes in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm learning Ruby in Codecademy and I'm stuck in the hashes lessons. i have problems reading how the key value pairs go into the hashes. So below is the code:

```
puts "Text please: "
text = gets.chomp

words = text.split(" ")
frequencies = Hash.new(0)
words.each {|word| frequencies[word] += 1}

frequencies = frequencies.sort_by {|word, count| count}

frequencies.reverse!

frequencies.each{|word, count| puts word + " " + count.to_s}
```

So this code is supposed to count word frequencies in the user's input. I'm a bit confused about the code `words.each {|word| frequencies[word] += 1}`...so does the frequency number go into the hashes every time the previous code runs through each word? Otherwise, how could a repeated word can get a count of 2?

It would be great that if anyone can explain to me a bit about the code  `words.each {|word| frequencies[word] += 1}`, so that I'll be able to understand the whole code block. Thank you so much!

Comment: What exactly confuses you? The square brackets in `frequencies[word]` or the `+=` operator or both?

Comment: If you've found any answers useful be sure to accept an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it assigns. `frequencies[word] += 1` is syntactic sugar for:

```
frequencies[word] = frequencies[word] + 1
```

which can be further rewritten as:

```
frequencies.[]=(word, frequencies[word] + 1)
```

Here, the method `[]=` is applied to the hash `frequencies`, which does the assignment. Each time this is called, `frequencies[word]` is reassigned a value one-incremented from its previous value.

Answer (score 1):

> frequencies = Hash.new(0)

In this line , means if the key not exist it will return 0 to you

> frequencies[word]

So if word is not exist it will return 0 to you , just as " return nil" while you just write

> frequencies = Hash.new

But notice that , if you didn't do anything for the value "0" , the key value will not be stored

> frequencies[word] += 1

So after this , the new value's stored by the key "word"

I think the reason why it uses 0 rather than nil is because 0 is more convenient to do calculation , while "nil" needs one more condition to judge , like this

> frequencies.store(word,0)  if  frequencies[word].nil?
>
> frequencies[word]+=1

Just try this , you will know how it works

> a=Hash.new(1)
>
> puts a['x']
>
> puts a.to_s
>
> puts a['x']+=1
>
> puts a.to_s